# Using source routing (LSRR) - any ideas?

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, routing

What I want to do is conceptually very simple, but I can't find any information or help about how to go about doing this.

Basically, I want to configure my networking to use source routing (LSRR). Now I know there are "security concerns" with this and hence it is generally blocked in the public Internet and so the tutorials reach dead ends. However I have a totally private network, and need to do this for some engineering reasons. [Basically, I'm doing some experiments where I want to "simulate" a hop by hop routing protocol]

So, I want to send traffic from (machine with IP address) A to (machine with IP address) X. But I want the traffic to follow a specific route via intermediate nodes B, C, then D i.e A -> B -> C -> D -> X. These are all private IP addresses and I have configured the proper ip_forwarding etc .

Ping actually allows you to use a LSRR, so I can ping from A to X via these intermediate nodes (using that route I specified) and can verify that it is actually happening with wireshack traces, and it works fine.

The question then is how can I use some features of iptables, or tun interfaces (or other - VPN?) etc to redirect all my normal traffic along this route using loose source routing? Basically, I would like to implement something at A, so that when I try to send traffic from A to X it intercepts those IP packets and adds the LSRR to them so that it forwards on via the specified intermediate points.

If anyone can help me, I would be extremely grateful as I can't seem to work out how to do this?

Thank you very much,
Triponi

Comment: This is not as simple: Those source route headers reduces the MTU.

Comment: Perhaps adapting RPL for use in Ethernet/Wi-Fi interfaces would work? There is a RPL implementation experiment for Linux https://github.com/linux-wpan/rpld that could be adapted to ignore the size requirement for EUI-64 to use MAC/EUI-48 for the associated interface.

Answer (score 1):

I set out to use the Loose Source and Record Route (LSRR) option for ssh/scp connections on my virtual network.  It's documented in RFC 791 (the original IP protocol spec).  Here is what I found.

I investigated using Linux eBPF to modify the packet headers (use `tc` to attach an eBPF program to modify matching packets), and while I still think this would work, other problems became apparent as I dug deeper.

First, we've got the `check_ip_options` routine in the stock `openssh` program explained with this comment:

```
/*
 * If IP options are supported, make sure there are none (log and
 * return an error if any are found).  Basically we are worried about
 * source routing; it can be used to pretend you are somebody
 * (ip-address) you are not. That itself may be "almost acceptable"
 * under certain circumstances, but rhosts authentication is useless
 * if source routing is accepted. Notice also that if we just dropped
 * source routing here, the other side could use IP spoofing to do
 * rest of the interaction and could still bypass security.  So we
 * exit here if we detect any IP options.
 */
```

So even if we get the LSRR option set on the packets, we need a modified `openssh` server for it to work with ssh or scp.  The change doesn't seem difficult; just comment out the `check_ip_options` code.  I decided that since I had to modify the `openssh` server anyway, I might as well modify the `openssh` client to set the LSRR option, as this seemed easier than using eBPF.  I got this far:

```
--- sshconnect.c.dist   2022-08-20 22:13:41.119013377 -0400
+++ sshconnect.c    2022-08-20 22:14:13.180812775 -0400
@@ -380,6 +380,10 @@
    }
    fcntl(sock, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC);
 
+   char lssr_option[] = {131, 0, 4, 192, 168, 4, 171};
+   lssr_option[1] = sizeof(lssr_option);
+   setsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_IP, IP_OPTIONS, lssr_option, sizeof(lssr_option));
+
    /* Bind the socket to an alternative local IP address */
    if (options.bind_address == NULL && options.bind_interface == NULL)
        return sock;
```

This code works.  Option 131 is LSRR and 192.168.4.171 is the address of my first hop.  Incidentally, the Linux networking code doesn't seem to copy this option directly into the packet, but instead swaps the address with the packet's destination address.  So, if you read RFC 791, you would expect to specify your final destination in `lssr_option`, but you should instead put your intermediate addresses there and use the final destination as your IP destination address.

Obviously I don't want my destination address hard-wired into the C code, and I should check the return value for errors, but it works.  I tested it out.  You need to configure all Linux systems along the path to accept source routes, like this:

```
echo 1 | sudo tee /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/accept_source_route
```

I also modified the openssh server by commenting out the call to `check_ip_options`.

The packets went through, but both wireshark and tcpdump reported bad TCP checksums, and I wasn't able to turn off TCP checksum offloading:

```
baccala@samsung:~/src/openssh-8.2p1$ sudo ethtool -K wlp1s0 tx off
Cannot change tx-checksumming
Could not change any device features
```

So maybe the WiFi card computes the TCP checksum, and it's not being done correctly when the LSRR options is present?  That's not difficult to believe, because the TCP checksum includes the destination address, and when LSRR is present the ultimate destination address is in the LSRR option, not the destination address field (which only contains the first hop).

I said "enough" and investigated other solutions.

I configured the virtual Linux routers to accept my ssh key, then used openssh's "jump host" option to tunnel through my network like this:

`ssh -J ubuntu@192.168.4.171,ubuntu@128.8.8.103 ubuntu@192.168.128.2`

I'm not trying to jump on the "you shouldn't even *want* to do that" bandwagon, but my experience was that ssh jump hosts were a far easier solution to my problem.

Comment: What is LSRR and where i can read about? Why dont use source routing with iproute?

Comment: @gaspf, I updated my answer to (among other things) at least decode the LSRR acronym and give a reference (RFC 791).  It's supposed to let you specify, in the IP packet headers, a list of IP address that the packets have to traverse to get to their destination.

Comment: This is an amazing answer that deserves so many more upvotes than it has. Any chance you can point to more info about how to set source routing with `tc`

Comment: @Codebling, I think you'd have to write an eBPF program.  I didn't find any worked example of an eBPF program to insert IP packet headers.

Comment: Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is pretty simple: Source routing creates many, many entertaining ways to wreak havoc, and is of little use in practice (perhaps for diagnosis, once each three blue moons). So most modern networking gear just ignores that.